# Can't seem to get the correct result by diagonalizing a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, diagonalization

I am trying to understand parts of the authors solution given to the following question:

> The generators of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ can be chosen as
> $$t^1=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -i \\\ 0 & i & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix},\ t^2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & i\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -i & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix},\ t^3=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0\\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
> Diagolizing $t^3$, find the $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ group element $\mathrm{R}(\theta)=\exp\left(-i\theta t^3\right)$.

---

The author's solution is:

> To diagonalize $t^3$, we first have to find its eigenvalues by solving
> $$\det\left(t^3-\mathbb{I}\lambda\right)=\det\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda & -i & 0\\ i & -\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\lambda \\ \end{pmatrix}=(\lambda^2-1)\times(-\lambda)=0$$
> The eigenvalues are therefore $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=\pm 1$. The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=0$ is clearly $\left(0,0,1\right)^T$ and the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=\pm 1$ are found by solving
> $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0\\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-ib\\ ia \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}=\pm \begin{pmatrix}a\\ b \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$
> which gives $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1,\pm i,0\right)\tag{2}$$ Therefore we can write $$t^3=U^\dagger \hat t U\tag{3}$$
> where
> $$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -i & 0\\ 1 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix},\tag{4}$$
> $$\hat t=\begin{pmatrix}+1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix},\tag{5}$$
> $$[....]$$

---

I don't need to type any more of the solution as I don't understand eqns. $(2)-(4)$.

Should eqn. $(2)$ actually read
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1,\pm i,0\right)^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mp i \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}, \, \text{for} \ \lambda=\pm 1?$$
If true then $t^3$ has eigenvectors
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -i \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \text{if}\,\,\lambda = +1\,\quad\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ i \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \text{if}\,\, \lambda = -1,\quad\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0 \\ \sqrt{2}\\ \end{pmatrix} \text{if}\,\, \lambda = 0\tag{a}$$

Then writing the matrix of eigenvectors, $U$, with the eigenvectors of $(\mathrm{a})$ as columns in the *same* order as the eigenvalues in $(5)$ should yield
$$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ -i & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2 & 0\\ -i/\sqrt2 & i/\sqrt2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
which is **not** the same as eqn. $(4)$. In fact, this is the *transpose* of eqn. $(4)$.

For eqn. $(3)$, $\det U = i$, $U$ is unitary (as the rows are orthonormal), so $U^\dagger=U^{-1}$.

In order to find the inverse of $U$, I first take its transpose
$$U^T=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt2 & -i/\sqrt2 & 0\\ 1/\sqrt2 & i/\sqrt2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}\tag{b}$$ then replacing each element of $(\mathrm{b})$ with its cofactor with the associated signature
$\begin{pmatrix}+ & - & +\\ - & + & - \\\ + & - & + \\ \end{pmatrix}$, I find that
$$U^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det U}\begin{pmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}i/\sqrt2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} & -\begin{vmatrix}1/\sqrt2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} & 0\\ -\begin{vmatrix}-i/\sqrt2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} & +\begin{vmatrix}1/\sqrt2 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & +\begin{vmatrix}1/\sqrt2 & -i/\sqrt2\\ 1/\sqrt2 & i/\sqrt2 \\ \end{vmatrix} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$=-i\begin{pmatrix}i/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 & 0\\ i/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & i & 0\\ 1 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Putting this altogether and omitting the [calculation details](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%7B%7B1%2Ci%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-i%2Ci%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D),

$$U^\dagger \hat t U=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1 & i & 0\\ 1 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}+1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ -i & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$$$=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\ne t^3\tag{c}$$

But using the version for $U$ as given in eqn. $(4)$ of the authors solution and again omitting the [calculation details](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7Bi%2C-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2Ci%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D),

$$U^\dagger \hat t U=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ i & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}+1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -i & 0\\ 1 & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$$$=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0\\ i & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} = t^3\tag{d}$$

Interestingly, if I write (with the omission of the [calculation details](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B-i%2Ci%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2Ci%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2CSqrt%5B2%5D%7D%7D)),
$$U \hat t U^\dagger=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ -i & i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}+1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & i & 0\\ 1 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$$$=\begin{pmatrix}0 & i & 0\\ -i & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}=-t^3\tag{e}$$

I've stared at this for sometime now but I just cannot understand why the author's solution, $(\mathrm{d})$, gives the correct result, but my attempt in eqn. $(\mathrm{c})$ $\big(\text{or}\, (\mathrm{e})\big)$ does not.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong here?

(Sorry for the lengthy post, I've trying to regain some linear algebra skills so needed to show a lot of working).

Comment: A diagonalized matrix $D=S^{-1}AS$ where the columns of $S$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. They've identified $U$ with $S^{-1}$ rather than $U$ with $S$. Also no need to invert by hand like that just take the conjugate transpose

Comment: @Sal Thanks for your comment. Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "invert by hand". I did take the conjugate transpose to arrive at the eigenvectors in $(\mathrm{a})$.

Comment: I meant: to invert $U$, you know that $U^{-1}=U^\dagger$ so there's no need to fiddle with cofactors etc. That doesn't resolve your issue, but I believe the first part of my previous comment does: you and the author just have different conventions for what you call $S$

Comment: @Sal If the author and myself are just using different conventions then we should both arrive at the same answer, but we get different answers: I do not end up with $t^3$ like the author does in eqn. $(\mathrm{d})$, instead I get $-t^3$ in eqn. $(\mathrm{e})$. It's important I understand why this is the case. Can you please explain further?

Comment: @Sal Do you agree that the author's eqn. $(2)$ is correct? Since the author wrote that $\left(0,0,1\right)^T$ (which I agree with since it is a column vector due the transpose symbol,) by my logic eqn. $(2)$ should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1,\pm i,0\right)^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \mp i \\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}, \, \text{for} \ \lambda=\pm 1$. Sorry if these questions seem trivial to you but I just can't understand how the author deduced that the matrix, $U$ in eqn. $(4)$ takes that form.